# AVPlayerLayer video is not visible

Tags: ios, video, avplayerlayer

I have an iOS APP, which can play videos.

It can play background.

When app will resign active, i remove the AVPlayerLayer, so the sound will go on.

And when app did become active, i attach the layer again, so the video come back.

All works well at iOS8 and iOS7.But....

Only when my player viewcontroller is not visible, i resign my app, and then come back and present my player viewcontroller, the video disappear (Only iOS7, iOS8 also works well)

anyone know about it?